# Html logging in unittest python framework

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am using unittest python framework. I am using `HTMLTestRunner` class to create html logs for the test cases. Only problem is that html logs are having logging for failed steps only. If test case is passed there is no logging. I am searching from last few days but could not able to do that

Can somebody guide me how to do that